# catkin_prepare_release pushes twice w/o incrementing tag?

Tags: ros, catkin, metapackage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran `catkin_prepare_release` once for the metapackage I maintain, then in [its commit history](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_robot_plugins/commits/groovy-devel), you can see commit message `0.2.12` twice on the same timestamp. Looking into the changes in each commit, the version defined in `package.xml` is incremented so that the latest is `0.2.13`. However the latest `tag` in the github repository still remains as `0.2.12`.

To summarize what I did not intend:

- Committed twice by running `catkin_prepare_release` only once
- If committing twice is necessary, tag is not yet updated in the 2nd commit

Is this intended behavior? If so, what steps are the next? I haven't notified buildfarm since this looks not good to me.

I admit that I was working in public wifi which might not be recommended for critical tasks like this, but I don't think the connection wasn't too bad.

Thanks!

ros-groovy-catkin 0.5.65-3quantal-20130325-0722-+0000

---

Update) command suggested by `catkin_prepare_release`:

```
../../../../../../../../../opt/ros/groovy/bin/catkin_package_version --bump patch . && git commit -m "0.2.12" rqt_runtime_monitor/package.xml rqt_robot_steering/package.xml rqt_tf_tree/package.xml rqt_robot_dashboard/package.xml rqt_pose_view/package.xml rqt_nav_view/package.xml rqt_robot_plugins/package.xml rqt_rviz/package.xml rqt_robot_monitor/package.xml && git push && git tag 0.2.12 && git push --tags
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60141/catkin_prepare_release-pushes-twice-w/o-incrementing-tag?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-04-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-04-09**:
FYI, next time tag with catkin or something common otherwise I don't get notified on this question.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-04-09**:
I would have to see the command that `catkin_prepare_release` gave you to run, it shouldn't commit twice.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-04-09**:
The posted output will not commit twice, you must have run that output twice, I bet if you look at the history then the second 0.2.12 will have package.xml which read 0.2.13... And they do, so I would say you must have accidentally run that stuff twice.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-04-09**:
Hm, `history` only returns a single line, but anyway sounds like it isn't a big deal. So I'll reset the last wrong commit (in this case 2nd 0.2.12). Do you want to re-post your last comment so that I'll mark it as an ans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found by myself that the version in `package.xml` gets incremented when `catkin_package_version` runs, even though authentication that subsequently comes after incrementation fails with the repository (`github` in my case). Since `catkin_package_version` repeats letting me try authentication, version can increment as many times as you fail + 1 success in the end.

I don't know if it's designed to do so or not but I opened [a ticket](https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/407).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-04-09**:
Yes, it is unsafe in that way, it just uses && to string commands together, so the first command runs even if the second one fails.